# Validation not firing in modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My Validation is not firing on my popup its showing the popup just fine just not doing the validation

```
<div>
    <form id="myForm">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Resitance, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address" })
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Resitance" class="text-danger"></span>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Passed, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Passed" })
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Passed" class="text-danger"></span>

        <select asp-for="CirtcutType"
                asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(ElectricalSurvey.DAL.Models.CircuitModel.CirtcutTypes))"
                class="form-control"></select>


        <div class="modal-footer">

            <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">@if (Model.Id > 0) {<span>Update</span> } else {<span>Save</span>} </a>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div style="text-align:center;display:none" id="loaderDiv">
        <img src="~/Content/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif" width="150" />
    </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $("#loaderDiv").show();
        var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Electrician/SaveCircuit",
            data: myformdata,
            success: function () {
                $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                $("#MyEditUpateModal").modal("hide");
                window.location.href = "/Electrician/Index";

            }

        })
    })

})
```

_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

To Note I am handing the dialog in html via following method.

```
 <script>
  var AddOrUpdateCircuit = function (id) {

    var url = "/Electrician/AddOrUpdateCircut?id=" + id;

    $("#myModalBodyDiv1").load(url, function () {
        $("#MyEditUpateModal").modal("show");

    })

}
```

Comment: You aren't triggering the form's submit event, which is when validation would normally happen

Comment: @ADyson Its being posted using Ajax

Comment: So? You can still trigger the submit event and then handle it

Answer (score 2):

This one will help you get started

```
<form id="myForm" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
```

and

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // do not execute actual submit.

    var form = $("#myForm")[0];
    form.classList.remove('was-validated');

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
       form.classList.add('was-validated');
       return;
    }

    $.ajax({
      //perform ajax
    });
})
```

Comment: Sorry should was-validated be on an item in the form so it can display such a label?

Comment: please see my ediit above its still not showing the errrors

Comment: You are right. Please check the updated solution. For test purposes you may replace <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span> with <div class="invalid-feedback">The field is required</div> By the way the post on the server side occurs or validation logic prevents that?